# Best Multithread Global Variable Management

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, c++11, c++17

I've looked at things like `std::atomic` (which doesn't work) and `std::mutex` (which is too much to manage) but nothing is working :( I'm using `std::thread` to create my threads, but I'm open to using `CreateThread()`

Here is the scenario: I have a variable that is constantly being updated in one thread. (say it's an int which reflects some value like number of dollars the user has) In the other threads, I access this variable, but do not write to it (just read). What can I do for this?

`std::atomic` doesn't store the information fast enough in the first thread, which results in really really broken values (say the user has $10, if I write $10 twice before `std::atomic` actually updates it, it'll be some obscure value like 28 million) - there's no "variable save queue" of any sort.

`std::mutex` just requires too much attention and ruins code readability.

What is the best way to manage these global variables? I'd love something as intuitive as `std::atomic`, since it manages everything for me, but preferably one that will satisfy my current dilemma.

Comment: "*if I write $10 twice before `std::atomic` actually updates it, it'll be some obscure value like 28 million*" That's not actually possible. `atomic` updates when you perform the operation; that's what it *means* to be "atomic". It's far more likely that you've written your code wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas then I have no idea what the issue is. Maybe it's the object size? the class that i'm storing atomically is something like `0xB800` in size

Comment: So you want atomic read and write on a class of size 0xB800? Or just an int inside it?

Comment: I Think you need to post some code

Comment: Entire class of size `0xB800` @Oliv

Comment: Hardware supports atomic memory operations only for very basic data types, such as integers and pointers. For more complex types, use mutex.

Comment: @4386427 sure, give me a second. It's hard to follow without know what the goal of the project is, which is why i made this question as objective as possible

Comment: You can also hide this mutex into the class itself. Then, I would recommend solution based on locking policies, which would allow to introduce no locking overhead into sequential code.

Comment: [Maybe transactional memory is a solution](http://pmarlier.free.fr/gcc-tm-tut.html). Depends on hardware or compiler support.

Comment: @J.Doe You might be interested in a library that I wrote: https://github.com/CarloWood/ai-threadsafe -- Note that license is AGPL, so not suitable for closed source.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a global mutex:

```
std::mutex my_global_variable_mutex;
```

You can define a function:

```
void im_doing_something_with_global_variable() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_global_variable_mutex);
    fun();
    // operations with global variable
    fun();
} // lock will be destroyed here; mutex is unlocked
```

and other function:

```
void im_doing_something_else_with_global_variable() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_global_variable_mutex);
    fun();
    // others operations with global variable
    fun();
} // lock will be destroyed here; mutex is unlocked
```

I think it is elegant, and easy;

+++++++++++++++

Version when one writer and many readers:

```
mutable std::shared_mutex my_global_variable_mutex;

void im_reading_global_variable() {
    std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> lock(my_global_variable_mutex);
    return my_global_variable;
} // lock will be destroyed here; mutex is unlocked

void im_doing_something_with_global_variable() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(my_global_variable_mutex);
    fun();
    // operations with global variable
    fun();
} // lock will be destroyed here; mutex is unlocked
```

Comment: He has one writer thread and many reader threads. A shared_mutex would be more adapted.

Comment: Yeah then shared_lock. edited

Comment: Please clarify ... what is "fun()" or perhaps what does "fun()" do?

Comment: fun() it's a function that you can implement and have some FUN in there with global variable. You ofc dont have to implement it. It's like foo but more fun.

Answer (score 0):

mutexes require hardly any attention, just use std::lock_guard guard(myMutex);, You don't have to worry about calling lock and unlock directly.

It's also easy to specialize lock_guard for custom types (a Windows CRITICAL_SECTION for example).